# Use jquery closest() to find closest element with a known sibling

Tags: jquery, xpath, closest, siblings

I am trying to use the jquery closest command to find a particular element based on if the element has a particular sibling. I have been playing with different selectors but haven't been able to find one yet that does what I want.

So for example, if the structure was something like the following

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                  <span a>cell 1</span>
                  <span>cell 2</span>
            </td>
            <td siblingmatch="true">
                  <span b>cell 1</span>
                  <span>cell 2</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <span siblingmatch="true">test 1</span>
</div>
```

If I ran closest starting from the span marked with a, I would want it to return it's parent td since it has a sibling marked with the siblingmatch attribute. However, if I ran the same command starting from the span marked with b, I would want it to return the table tag since this is the first parent it finds with a sibling marked with the siblingmatch attribute.

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: Show the jquery code you've been playing around with as well. It'll give something more to work with.

Comment: @undefined I think it's clear that `<span a>` (and b) are just exemplary to indicate the text after the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `parents` and `filter` methods.

```
$('span').click(function(){
    var matched = $(this).parents().filter(function(){
         return $(this).siblings('[siblingmatch]').length;
    }).first();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WW5qL/

Note that `siblingmatch` is not a valid attribute, you can use HTML5 `data-*` attributes instead.

Comment: Yes, siblingmatch wasn't the actual attribute name, just something for this example.

I ran your example and that does seem to return what I want. I noticed you are not using the closest() function in your code, instead the parents filter. Is there a reason to use one vs another and could I do the same thing with closest()?

Comment: Responding to my own comment: closest() doesn't support a function, so that would require a selector, which is where I was struggling. The parents().filter() allows a function, so that provides a little more flexibility.

Comment: @bbeaudet `closest` only returns matching parent element (_specified by the selector_), it's not a useful method to be used here vs `parents` returns all the parent elements of the selected element (_most of the times I do not use this function_) which allows filtering them. Note that both of the functions do not accept `function`, using `filter` is a chainability that jQuery provides.